# Set Order of Columns in SqlAlchemy before writing to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I'm trying to set the order of columns when building a table with SQLAlchemy, as of right now the columns are appearing in alphabetical order, I currently have:

```
def data_frame(query, columns):
    def make_row(x):
        return dict([(c, getattr(x, c)) for c in columns]) 
    return pd.DataFrame([make_row(x) for x in query])

PackL = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://u:pass@Server/db1?driver=SQL Server', echo=False)
Fabr = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://u:pass@Server/db2?driver=SQL Server', echo=False)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=PackL)
session = Session()
Base = declarative_base()
metadata = MetaData()

class Tranv(Base):
    __tablename__= "Transactions"
    __table_args__= {'autoload': True, 'autoload_with':PackL}

newvarv = session.query(Tranv).filter_by(status='SCRAP').filter(Tranv.time_stamp.
between('2015-10-01', '2015-10-09'))

session.close()

dfx = data_frame(newvarv, ['action', 'employee_number', 'time_stamp', 'qty', 
'part_number', 'card_number'])
```

Current dfx has the columns in alphabetical order, but I want it to order them by the order in which I define the columns when I create the data frame dfx. Therefore the order would be action, employee_number, time_stamp, qty, part_number, card_number. I can easily do this with Pandas, but that seems like extra (and unnecessary) steps.

I've searched the documentation, google, & stackoverflow but nothing really seems to fit my needs. As I'm still new with SQLAlchemy I appreciate any help. Am I right in thinking that because I'm autoloading the table, I can not easily define the order of my columns (I'm sure there is a workaround, but don't have a clue where in the documentation that might be found)?

Comment: I think you could also use `dfx = pd.read_sql_query(newvarv, PackL)` to convert the query to a dataframe isntead of writing your own method (but not fully sure).

Comment: To comment on my own comment, you need to pass `newvarv.selectable`, see my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your columns are not in the order you specify, has nothing to do with the sql query or sqlalchemy. This is caused by the fact that you convert the query output to a dictionary, which you then feed to `DataFrame`.
As a dictionary has no order in python, pandas will sort it alphabetically to have a predictable output.

Using the current approach of the dict, you can always change the order of the columns afterwards by doing `dfx.reindex(columns=['action', ..., 'card_number'])`

---

Apart from the explanation why it is not ordered in your case, there are maybe better approaches to tackle this:

- Use the builtin `pd.read_sql_query`. When working with sessions and Query objects, you can pass the `selectable` attribute to `read_sql_query` to convert it to a DataFrame:

  ```
  query = session.query(Table)...
  df = pd.read_sql_query(query.selectable, engine)
  ```
- Do not convert to a dictionary, but keep the output as tuples which you feed to `DataFrame`: this will keep the order of the query output.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense; was not thinking about the query output conversion. I've tried the pd.read_sql_query before (in fact I took out my data_frame function & replaced it with your earlier comment) but I always got this error: sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Unexecutable object type: <class 'sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query'>

Comment: Yes, sorry, you are correct. But, you can pass the `selectable` property of the Query object: `pd.read_sql_query(query.selectable, engine)`. This, way, you don't need your own written method to convert it to a dataframe.

Comment: Thank you, this is probably the simplest solution and certainly more approachable than what I was doing before.